# Javascript and clientId issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi guys I have a user control:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" readonly="readonly" />
 <img src="../images/remove.png" id="test" onclick="ClearFeild()" runat="server" />
```

My aspx page looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="server">

    <uc:Calendar ID="calSample" runat="server" ChangeMonth="false" ChangeYear="false"
        DateFormat="dd-M-yy" TextBoxWidth="75px" Enabled="true" />
    <uc:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ChangeMonth="false" ChangeYear="false"
        DateFormat="dd-M-yy" TextBoxWidth="75px" Enabled="true" />
</asp:Content>
```

And on the user control I have a javascript function that gets called on the img onclick:

```
    function ClearFeild()
    {     
       debugger; 
       $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").val() = "";
    }
```

but the value of

> $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>");

is always :

> $("#ContentPlaceHolderBody_Calendar1_datepicker");

which is the second user control, even though i click on the first control.

PLease assist as to how i can over come this.

The CLearFeild function gets called on a button click to clear the datepicker feild.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is the same problem as seen in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512440/x-clientid-in-repeated-user-control-returning-wrong-value); I answered it there so won't copy/paste my answer, but hopefully it should be of use to you. Basically change `onclick="ClearFeild()"` to `onclick="ClearFeild('<%=datepicker.ClientID %>')"` and `function ClearFeild()` to `function ClearFeild(id)` and use the `id` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the source object to your function

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrq8b/1/)**

```
onclick="ClearFeild(this)"

function ClearFeild(source) {        
    obj = $('#' + source.id)
    prevInput = obj.prev('input[type=text]')
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but that wont work as i am trying to clear the datepicker text field. So passing this in the ClearFeild method would get the ID of the img control and not the input text control.

Comment: Updated my answer to access previous input field. You are required to have unique ids for html controls though.

Comment: Okay, got it, I changed:
prevInput = $(this).prev('input')
to:
prevInput = $(img).prev('input')

Comment: Did little modification, check it now. I also included live demo.

Comment: Is it possible to set the value of prevInput?

Comment: Yes, prevInput.val("new value");

Comment: Ahhh thanks so much! i was trying prevInput.val() = "";

Stupid mistake!!! 

Thanks again! Much appreciated!

Comment: I am trying to use this again, but I now have jQuery vallidation on th field, and if the validation fails obj.prev() gets the label now instead of the textbox, please help on how to solve this issue

Comment: try using obj.prev('label')

Comment: I do not want to get the label, i still need to clear the texbox.

Comment: This will clear that textbox, obj.prev('input[type=text]').val('');

Comment: when validation fails it does not clear the text box, but otherwise it does.

Comment: I've checked obj.prev(), and this only has the label object that displayed the validation error and not the textbox.

Comment: I solved this by checking obj.prev()[0].htmlFor, if it is ==  "undefined" then prevInput = obj.prev('input[type=text]').val(""); else  $('#' + obj.prev()[0].htmlFor).val(""); this works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your js call would reach the nearest javascript method available.

Since it is in user control, it might be rendered twice. So you are reaching the second method which is closer.

Rendered output will look like

```
function ClearField(){$("#ContentPlaceHolderBody_calSample_datepicker")}
function ClearField(){$("#ContentPlaceHolderBody_Calendar1_datepicker")}
```

and **your HTML output here**.

Try passing image reference with **this** keyword then find input text box which has a class

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker-box" id="datepicker" runat="server" readonly="readonly" />
 <img src="../images/remove.png" id="test"
        onclick="ClearFeild(this)" runat="server" />


 function ClearFeild(img)
    {     

        var dateTextBox= $(img).closest('input.datepicker-box');
    }
```